# When we need Collections class method in Arraylist then why not Collections is extended?

Tags: java

`Collections.sort()` is needed each and every time in  `Arraylist` when we perform sorting , so why not "The great man" who has developed `Arraylist`  does not added `Collections` class as extended class !

Comment: Is your question "why is there no sort method on ArrayList" ?

Comment: yes my question is "why is there no sort method on ArrayList"    @dystroy

Comment: `Collections` is just a class containing a bunch of useful methods. You don't want to `extend` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well may be because of the following reasons

1. ArrayList already extends AbstractList and you can extends only one class in java
2. All the functions of Collections are static
3. They do not want anyone to override the methods in case in was not static
4. If one argues that they can be converted into final non static methods then making Collections as the base class would be of no use.
5. Methods in Collections are just a part of job which can be executed on ArrayList and it does not defines what ArrayList should do. Hence from an OOP point of view I, neither "The great man" would have done that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the sort(list) implementation in the `Collections` class :

```
132     public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
133         Object[] a = list.toArray();
134         Arrays.sort(a);
135         ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
136         for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
137             i.next();
138             i.set((T)a[j]);
139         }
140     }
```

You see it's generic and operates on all instances of any implementation of `List`.

`List` being an interface, you couldn't have this implementation as instance method of `List`, and this avoid duplicating it in every concrete implementation. That's why it's better to have those methods defined in a third party class, `Collections`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Collections` is a utility class , `ArrayList` is a data structure . They both exists for different purpose. `Collections.sort()` is a utility method to sort a `List`, keeping this in a single place avoids redundancy in code.
2. `Collections.sort()` is a static method , so it cannot be overridden.
3. If any `List` implementation extends `Collections` class , then it will not be able to extend any other class in future.